# React router Link adding extra route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im not sure whats going on here. But all the information is in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/Munsterberg/1f72e11226173749c8472217132d4c68

You can see the comment with an image that shows the URL that it adds an extra `/admin/` in the redirect. When I visit `equipment/new` route which has the same format as the Link I am using in the gist, it works fine. Also if I visit the route and go back and then forward it cant find the route location. If I take away the admin in the Link it doesnt match any routes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the link to

```
<Link to={`/admin/forum-administration/${props.forum.forumNo}/threads`}>{props.forum.description}</Link>
```

Which renders `route` from the `root`.

Since your

```
<Link to={`admin/forum-administration/${props.forum.forumNo}/threads`}>{props.forum.description}</Link>
```

pushes the router to link `admin/forum-administration/${props.forum.forumNo}/threads` that appends to current parent route `/admin/...`

Comment: First one worked, thank you! Silly mistake on my end